# qmlRegisterType read access violation moving from Qt5.15.10 to Qt6.3

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm currently refactoring our codebase to move from Qt5.15.10 to Qt6.3 and I am getting a read access violation error when creating a qmlRegisterType that worked in Qt5.15.10. I've been looking around and can't find any reason why it isn't working.  Did they change something about creating qmlRegisterTypes?

Comment: "Did they change something about creating qmlRegisterTypes?" - maybe. Why don't you check the public release notes documents and the public git repositories for info on that? That's what most people would do.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by moving to Qt 6.2.5 instead of 6.3.  Qt 6.2 is an LTS release,